# What is rotor torque?

Tags: torque, stepper-motor

On my stepper's [datasheet](http://download.lulzbot.com/AO-100/hardware/electronics/spec_sheets/SY42STH47-1504A_stepperMotors.pdf), it has the category "rotor torque" (labeled in N-CM). **What does that mean? Is this the torque it has can supply when turning? (Hopefully)**

Comment: Thanks for your flag, but the the reason this was marked as a duplicate is that although the question is not quite the same, the answers to that question answer your question anyway. If you feel those answers do not sufficiently answer your question, feel free to edit this question making it clear what you do not understand. After editing your question, flag it for moderator attention and we can re-open it.